Cannot view Django application installed with helm on Minikube
I have packaged a custom helm chart and did
helm install announcements /helm
When I go to kubectl get pods and kubectl get deploy it shows the pods and deployments are up.
However, when I try to go to the Service IP to see the application, it hangs. I then try to do the command given by the helm install:
export SERVICE_IP=$(kubectl get svc --namespace default announcements-helm --template "{{ range (index .status.loadBalancer.ingress 0) }}{{.}}{{ end }}")
And then I get the error:
error: error executing template "{{ range (index .status.loadBalancer.ingress 0) }}{{.}}{{ end }}": template: output:1:10: executing "output" at <index .status.loadBalancer.ingress 0>: error calling index: index of untyped nil
I'm very new to Helm and Kubernetes, so I'm not sure what to try to fix this. Any advice?

If you have a LoadBalancer-type Service, there's an implicit assumption that something will create a load balancer for you and fill in the Service, but this doesn't necessarily happen on Minikube.  If you kubectl get service announcements-helm -o yaml, is there anything under status: { loadBalancer: }?

It says status: loadBalancer: {}
Is there a way to set this up on Minikube or do I have to do this on a cloud provider? Alternatively is there another service I could use to get the app to expose? I've tried NodePort and ClusterIP but still couldn't see the application. Thank you!

Does Access Minikube Loadbalancer Service From Host Machine have the information you need?  If you can change your Kubernetes manifests to use an Ingress endpoint instead of a LoadBalancer-type Service, you also may be able too use the Nginx ingress controller.

I was able to see the NGINX service again, but not the Django application. Is there something I could be missing configuration wise to get the NGINX to point to Django?
